# is there a difference between prefix and postfix increment in solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix

I am using a simple solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;


contract Counter {
uint public count = 1;

function incrementCount() public {
    ++count; // one way to do this
    count++; //another way to do this
}
```

}

since solidity is inspired by C, I am wondering if there is any difference between prefix and postfix increment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like in other programming languages, in Solidity the prefix/postfix operator means that the place of the `++` or `--` determines what will happen next.

From the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#operators-involving-lvalues):

> `a++` and `a--` are equivalent to `a += 1` / `a -= 1` but the expression
> itself still has the previous value of `a`. In contrast, `--a` and `++a`
> have the same effect on `a` but return the value after the change.

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Counter {
 
    uint public count = 1;

    function incrementPrefixCount() public returns (uint) {
        return (++count); // returns 2
    }
    
    function incrementPostfixCount() public returns (uint) {
        return (count++); // returns 1
    }
}
```